# Is a statue made of bronze called bronzed or brazed?

Tags: word-choice

When do you use bronzed vs. brazed?  Is a bronze statue bronzed or brazed?

What would be the best word for a man that was commemorated with a bronze statue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're attempting to describe a bronze statue, then *bronze statue* would be the best descriptor.

- *Brazed* means to solder a joint.
- *Bronzed* means that something is coated in bronze, not made of it.
- *Brazen* means that something is made of brass, which is different than bronze.

Comment: +1 for hitting the difference between "brazed" and "brazen".

Answer (score 2):

*A bronze* is also a noun for a statue
*He was honoured by a life-sized bronze of himself*

Answer (score 1):

- "Bronzed" means plated in bronze like bronzed baby shoes
- "Brazen" (which I think is the word you're looking for) is an archaic word that means made of bronze.
- "Brazed" is the past tense of braze which is a process of joining two pieces of metal that is somewhat similar to soldering. (thanks [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/braze))

edited for clarity.

Comment: By the way, when you edit something there is a convenient "Edit Summary" at the bottom of the page where you can let people know what and why you edited. The summary is visible by clicking on the "5 mins ago" link next to "edited." You don't need to add the reason to the body of the answer itself. (But great edit, by the way! It is certainly much easier to read now.)

Comment: _Brazen_ doesn't mean "made of bronze;" it means "made of brass." Brass is a different copper alloy.

Comment: @MrHen Thanks, I realized as I was clicking the Save button. Well, always next time.
@kiamlaluno I didn't know that brazen referred to brass, thanks.